# Prevent service brltty and qemu-kvm from starting

Tags: startup, services

So, I do Arduino development on my system to program arduinos using the FTDI USB programming interface (if you have no idea what this means don't worry).

The issue arises because the FTDI interface uses tty to communicate and it conflicts with one of the default ubuntu services.

The default service in question is called brltty (which enables braille accessibility for people with impaired vision). Considering that I don't have any particular use for this service and it's annoying to stop it manually (using 'service brltty stop') after I restart my system...

Where would I configure this (or any) service to prevent it from loading on startup?

*Note: I also have this issue with qemu-kvm conflicting with virtualbox.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `brltty` package if you don't need it.

```
sudo apt-get remove brltty
```

---

As for qemu-kvm service, there is an easy solution too. `sudoedit` your `/etc/init/qemu-kvm.conf` and correct the line

> start on runlevel [2345]

to

> start on runlevel [345]

System's default [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) is 2.

Comment: +1 While that's the easy solution, it's not really what I'm looking for. For instance, I'd like to remove the auto-start on the qemu-kvm service (because I still use it) but I don't want to bother with starting/stopping it every time I load virtualbox (because I use virtualbox a lot more than qemu-kvm).

Comment: @Evan see update.